# How can I reduce duplicate code in computing eigenvalues/eigenvectors?

Tags: c++

I wrote a toy project of matrix library in C++.
It is able to compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors correctly.
I want to distinguish two APIs, one is that the user would want to compute only eigenvalues, and the other is that the user would want to get their corresponding eigenvectors as well.
The problem is that, there are too many duplicate code.

My current code is:

```
} // anonymous namespace

template <typename Derived, isScalar U, isScalar T = CmpTypeT<U>> requires CmpTypeTo<U, T>
std::vector<T> eigenval(const MatrixBase<Derived, U, 2>& M) {
    std::size_t n = M.dims(0);
    std::size_t C = M.dims(1);
    if (n != C) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Not a square Matrix, cannot compute eigenvalues");
    }

    if (n == 1) { // 1 x 1
        return {M[{0, 0}]};
    } else if (n == 2) { // 2 x 2
        return eigenTwo(M);
    } else if (n == 3) { // 3 x 3
        return eigenThree(M);
    } else { // for 4 x 4 we need advanced algorithm
        auto H = Hessenberg(M);
        return QRIteration(H);
    }
}

template <typename Derived, isScalar U, isScalar T = CmpTypeT<U>> requires CmpTypeTo<U, T>
std::vector<std::pair<T, Vec<T>>> eigenvec(const MatrixBase<Derived, U, 2>& M) {
    std::size_t n = M.dims(0);
    std::size_t C = M.dims(1);
    if (n != C) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Not a square Matrix, cannot compute eigenvalues");
    }

    if (n == 1) { // 1 x 1
        auto val = M[{0, 0}];
        Vec<T> vec {T{1}};
        return {{val, vec}};
    } else if (n == 2) { // 2 x 2
        return eigenVecTwo(M);
    } else if (n == 3) { // 3 x 3
        return eigenVecThree(M);
    } else { // for 4 x 4 we need advanced algorithm
        auto [H, V] = HessenbergWithVec(M);
        return QRIterationWithVec(H, V);
    }
}
```

`HessenbergWithVec` and `Hessenberg` are mostly the same.
`QRIterationWithVec` and `QRIteration` are mostly the same as well.
Few different things are computing eigenvectors from eigenvalues. And return type of these functions are different.

How can I minimize duplicate code here?

FYI, detailed implementation of `Hessenberg` and `HessenbergWithVec`:

```
template <typename Derived, isScalar U, isScalar T = ScalarTypeT < U>> requires ScalarTypeTo<U, T>
Mat<T> Hessenberg(const MatrixBase<Derived, U, 2>& mat, bool both = false) {
    std::size_t n = mat.dims(0);
    std::size_t C = mat.dims(1);
    if (n != C) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Not a square matrix, cannot transform to Hessenberg");
    }
    if (n < 3) {
        return mat;
    }

    auto conjif = [&](const auto& v) {
        if constexpr (isComplex<U>) {
            return conj(v);
        } else {
            return v;
        }
    };

    Mat<T> H = mat;

    if (both) { // we want both upper and lower Hessenberg! (tridiagonal)
        // Note: the original matrix should be symmetric in this case.
        for (std::size_t k = 0; k < n - 1; ++k) {
            // erase below subdiagonal
            auto ck1 = H.col(k).submatrix(k + 1);
            if (norm(ck1) > tolerance_soft) {
                auto vk1 = Householder(ck1);
                // apply Householder from the left
                auto Sub1 = H.submatrix({k + 1, k});
                Sub1 -= outer(vk1, dot(2.0f * conjif(vk1), Sub1));
            }

            // erase right of superdiagonal
            auto ck2 = H.row(k).submatrix(k + 1);
            if (norm(ck2) > tolerance_soft) {
                auto vk2 = Householder(ck2);
                // apply Householder from the right
                auto Sub2 = H.submatrix({k, k + 1});
                Sub2 -= outer(dot(Sub2, 2.0f * vk2), conjif(vk2));
            }
        }
    } else { // nope, upper Hessenberg is enough. (default)
        for (std::size_t k = 0; k < n - 2; ++k) {
            // (n - k - 1) x 1
            auto ck = H.col(k).submatrix(k + 1);
            if (norm(ck) < tolerance_soft) {
                continue;
            }
            auto vk = Householder(ck);

            // apply Householder from the left
            auto Sub1 = H.submatrix({k + 1, k});
            Sub1 -= outer(vk, dot(2.0f * conjif(vk), Sub1));

            // apply Householder from the right
            auto Sub2 = H.submatrix({0, k + 1});
            Sub2 -= outer(dot(Sub2, 2.0f * vk), conjif(vk));
        }
    }

    return H;
}


template <typename Derived, isScalar U, isScalar T = ScalarTypeT<U>> requires ScalarTypeTo<U, T>
std::pair<Mat<T>, Mat<T>> HessenbergWithVec(const MatrixBase<Derived, U, 2>& mat) {
    std::size_t n = mat.dims(0);
    std::size_t C = mat.dims(1);
    Mat<T> V = identity<T>(n);
    if (n != C) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Not a square matrix, cannot transform to Hessenberg");
    }
    if (n < 3) {
        return {mat, V};
    }

    auto conjif = [&](const auto& v) {
        if constexpr (isComplex<U>) {
            return conj(v);
        } else {
            return v;
        }
    };

    Mat<T> H = mat;


    for (std::size_t k = 0; k < n - 2; ++k) {
        // (n - k - 1) x 1
        auto ck = H.col(k).submatrix(k + 1);
        if (norm(ck) < tolerance_soft) {
            continue;
        }
        auto vk = Householder(ck);

        // apply Householder from the left
        auto Sub1 = H.submatrix({k + 1, k});
        Sub1 -= outer(vk, dot(2.0f * conjif(vk), Sub1));

        // apply Householder from the right
        auto Sub2 = H.submatrix({0, k + 1});
        Sub2 -= outer(dot(Sub2, 2.0f * vk), conjif(vk));
        auto VSub2 = V.submatrix({0, k + 1});
        VSub2 -= outer(dot(VSub2, 2.0f * vk), conjif(vk));
    }

    return {H, V};
}
```

EDIT: I tried to unify two function with return type `std::vector<std::pair<T, std::optional<Vec<T>>>>`, but reactions from API users (mostly friends of mine) were bad. Any better idea?

Comment: Most obvious thing - extract repeating parts to a smaller function and reuse in both implementations. And I think you should post it not here but in codereview part of stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

I am not trying to compile any code, only give you suggestions that you might have to work further

The Hessenberg could be simplified by checking if you need tridiagonal inside the loop. Since the complexity of the loop is already linear, this refactoring will not have a significant impact on the code performance but will result in a simpler code.

```c++
template <typename Derived, isScalar U, isScalar T = ScalarTypeT < U>> requires ScalarTypeTo<U, T>
Mat<T> Hessenberg(const MatrixBase<Derived, U, 2>& mat, bool both = false) {
    std::size_t n = mat.dims(0);
    std::size_t C = mat.dims(1);
    if (n != C) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Not a square matrix, cannot transform to Hessenberg");
    }
    if (n < 3) {
        return mat;
    }

    auto conjif = [&](const auto& v) {
        if constexpr (isComplex<U>) {
            return conj(v);
        } else {
            return v;
        }
    };

    Mat<T> H = mat;

       for (std::size_t k = 0; k < n - 1; ++k) {
            // erase below subdiagonal
            auto ck1 = H.col(k).submatrix(k + 1);
            if (norm(ck1) > tolerance_soft) {
                auto vk1 = Householder(ck1);
                // apply Householder from the left
                auto Sub1 = H.submatrix({k + 1, k});
                Sub1 -= outer(vk1, dot(2.0f * conjif(vk1), Sub1));
            }
            if (!both) continue
            // we want both upper and lower Hessenberg! (tridiagonal)
            // Note: the original matrix should be symmetric in this case.
     
            // erase right of superdiagonal
            auto ck2 = H.row(k).submatrix(k + 1);
            if (norm(ck2) > tolerance_soft) {
                auto vk2 = Householder(ck2);
                // apply Householder from the right
                auto Sub2 = H.submatrix({k, k + 1});
                Sub2 -= outer(dot(Sub2, 2.0f * vk2), conjif(vk2));
            }
        }
    

    return H;
}
```

For the eigenvector and eigenvalue thing I would compute create a function that computes a submatrix of `m` eigenvectors, then I would call it with `m=0` when I only want eigenvalues, and `m=n` when I want all the eigenvalues.

About your friend preferences about the return values I cannot give any suggestion.